# Nested 'where in' statement in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query:

```
select sum(qty) as 'total' from `sales_flat_quote_item`
where item_id not in (
  select item_id from `sales_flat_quote_item_option`
  where item_id in (
    select item_id from `sales_flat_quote_item`
    where quote_id = 12670
  ) 
  and code = 'is_gift'
)
and quote_id = 12670 and parent_item_id is null
```

My task is make this query using JOIN clause. Well query itself is quite weird. `sales_flat_quote_item` is used in both query and subquery. This cause some efficient issues.

I'm not SQL expert, so I'm asking you. I can handle one lvl of nested `select` queries on my own, but I don't know what to do in this situation.

We use Mysql db engine v. 5.1

---

I was able to make it like this:

```
select A.qty, A.item_id from `sales_flat_quote_item` as A 
where A.item_id not in 
(
    select B.item_id from 
    `sales_flat_quote_item_option` as B
    inner join `sales_flat_quote_item` as C
    on C.item_id = B.item_id
    where B.code = 'is_gift' and
    C.quote_id = 834
)
and A.quote_id = 834 and A.parent_item_id is null
```

Is it possible to make it without using any sub-queries?

Answer (score 1):

To work this one out you need to work from the inside out. Figure out what the inner most query returns, then match that result against the where clause, continue until you reach the top.

```
select item_id 
from `sales_flat_quote_item` 
where quote_id = 12670
```

This gives you a list of item_id's where the quote_id is 12670.

```
select item_id 
from `sales_flat_quote_item_option`
where item_id in (Previous Result Set)   
and code = 'is_gift'
```

This gives you a list of item_id's where the item_id is contained in the previous list AND the code column = 'is_gift'

```
select sum(qty) as 'total' 
from `sales_flat_quote_item`     
where item_id not in (Previous Result Set) 
and quote_id = 12670 and parent_item_id is null
```

This returns the sum total of the qty field and names it 'total' where the item_id is not in the previous result set AND has a quote_id of 12670 and does not have a parent_item_id.

That should be enough for you to re-craft your query, but if your still having trouble post me a comment and I'll see if I can rewrite it given the above information (sans table designs).

Comment: well, the `select item_id from \`sales_flat_quote_item_option\` where item_id in (Previous Result Set) and code = 'is_gift'` returns null...

Comment: Please tell me you didn't execute that verbatim? Previous Result Set was me saying "get the results of the previous query and put them here".

Comment: I'm not retarded you know ;) I just paste your code to save some space. 2nd level query returns null for that quote_id = 12670 :)

Comment: Thank god! You never know with this site =) well if that query returns null then really the query is just select sum(qty) as 'total' from `sales_flat_quote_item` WHERE quote_id = 12670 and parent_item_id is null. As the middle nest returns nothing that means it selects where the item_id is not in NULL which should be all of them depending on your table design.